# 2017 Kia Sorento Dual Climate - how is it suppose to work

Tags: ac, kia, hvac

When I start my AC on low for both sides, air is blowing cold as expected. When I turn driver side up to say 72 degrees, it seems like the passenger side gets a little warmer but I don't think 72 warmer though but definitely not cold anymore.

Does dual climate systems split the difference, or could you actually have one side hot and other side cold?

Answer (score 1):

> Does dual climate systems split the difference, or could you actually
> have one side hot and other side cold?

They are supposed to be independent of each other but in my experience they don't quite do it.

The problem is that they both rely on the same source of heat or cold and there is just so much of either to go around.  So if one side maxes out the heat the other side may notice that they don't get as much heat.

What you describe may be normal but it's also possible that there is some leaking in the "doors" (called blend doors) that control the temperatures on each side that is causing this behavior.  Unfortunately, in most vehicles the HVAC parts are tucked up under the dash and are quite difficult to get to.  In other words it can be costly to get them looked at.